# How to iterate and dynamically parameterize JPQL queries?

Tags: jsf, seam, iteration, el, parameterized-query

I have a page with simple ID as a URL param. What I do now is run a query to return a number of associated entities that basically need to get iterated over: I need a schedule of games to be returned for LEAGUE games, CUP games, and PLAYOFFS games, so the result lists must differ per iteration.

Each of these schedules gets its own tab in the GUI. I already need JSTL c:forEach for the RichFaces tabs, so I "only" need to find a way to set another WHERE restriction onto a component (here a Seam EntityQuery sub class instance).

The problem here is: How do you parameterize each query with the current entity during iteration? How is it best done in Seam/JBoss EL? How do I get another restriction or two into an EntityQuery instance during iteration?

Here's the JSF code I use:

```
<rich:tabPanel>
  <c:forEach items="#{participationListQuery.resultList}" var="pa">
    <rich:tab label="#{...}" switchType="client">
      <h:form>
      <rich:dataTable id="schedule-scores"
                      value="#{rosterScheduleQuery.resultList}"
                      var="sgl"
                      width="100%"
                      rows="20">
        ...
      </rich:dataTable>
      </h:form>
    </rich:tab>
  </c:forEach>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

The problem here is you can't simply call something like `#{rosterScheduleQuery.setCustomRestriction(pa.group.round.subCompetition.competition.name)}` in the c:forEach as this expression will only be evaluated once (if I understand correctly). I might be missing the overall point here, as this is all rather procedural.

How do you generally solve iteration and runtime-parameterized queries (additional WHERE conditions)? Best practices are always welcome.

Thanks

Edit: I'm already using Facelets, but rich:tabPanel requires JSTL c:forEach to be used. See http://relation.to/11633.lace.

Comment: Could you use Facelets instead of JSP? You could then use `<ui:repeat>` instead of `<c:forEach>`, which should work in this situation. I appreciate that changing to Facelets is a drastic step though.

Comment: You want a dynamically generated set of tab panels, one for each schedule?  Any particular reason why you want these all generated when the page is loaded using the "client" switch type, rather than when the tab panel is clicked?  In other words, is "ajax" switch type an option?  And then you run the query when the tab is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I want one schedule per tab. I need to adjust the query slightly per tab, that is per game type, so the problem in general is how to get a value into the query instance per iteration, which is actually only instantiated per request. Setting something on the query doesn't seem to work. The schedule is always the one from the first tab. Maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

JBossEL allows method calls with parameters, so you could add an intermediate bean that has a method that takes the type and retrieves the results. Basically replace "#{rosterScheduleQuery.resultList}" with "#{someNewBean.getResults(pa)}". This bean would have the query injected into it, which it could parameterize as needed. Probably not as elegant as you would like, but I think this is how I would do it.

Comment: I'll have to look at this. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed you said the `rosterScheduleQuery` is already an EntityQuery subclass, so you don't need the "intermediate bean" that I said before. You can just add the restriction method to you query class.

Comment: I implemented rosterScheduleQuery.getResultListFor(Participation pa) which returns the same list of entities via return super.getResultList(), but there's **no change** at all. The schedule is always the same for each tab. I then found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170296/how-does-scope-type-affect-the-way-an-entityquery-object-is-re-used. However, using refresh(), setMaxResults(getMaxResults), ... or any other call prior to super.getResultList() seems to result in an infinite loop. The browser tries to load the page but doesn't stop. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to mix both JSP and JSF handlers. You are using *switchType* equal To *client* which means its content will be prerendered to the client, and **no interaction with the server will happen** during switching.

Well, it can not be the best solution, but i think it can help you

```
<rich:tabPanel value="#{participationTabPanel}">
</rich:tabPanel>
```

You managed bean

```
@Name
public class ParticipationManagedForm {

    private @In EntityQuery<Participation> participationListQuery;

    @Factory(value="participationTabPanel", scope=ScopeType.EVENT)
    public HtmlTabPanel getParticipationTabPanel() {
        HtmlTabPanel panel = new HtmlTabPanel();

        for(List<Participation> participationList: participationListQuery.getResultList()) {
            HtmlTab htmlTab = new HtmlTab();

            // Set up htmlTab right here

            panel.getChildren().add(htmlTab);
        }

        return panel;
    }

}
```